# Windows 8 graphics corruption and clock wrong

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, windows-explorer, troubleshooting

I have a user who is reporting the following problem with a Windows 8 Dell all-in-one desktop:

> The desktop goes black at times and image sections of documents overlap onto other screens.  The tools on the bottom left disappear.  For example the clock in the corner will disappear and then reappear but not show the correct time.

At first I thought a display driver problem may be causing this.  I rolled the driver back to the previous version, before the last Windows Update.
However, it appears the issue continues to occur periodically.

Because of the statement about the clock being wrong when it reappears, it sounds like Explorer might be crashing.  However, I'm puzzled by the display corruption.

Any suggestions to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to get a screenshot? It might also be worth uninstalling the graphics drivers and seeing if the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter has the same issue.

Comment: @Sonickyle27 good idea.  So does it sound like a graphics card/driver issue to you?  Can you think of any reason other than Explorer crashing, which would cause the clock to disappear, then be wrong when it reappears?

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.komprogram.pl/stackoverflow/screen-artifact4.jpg) it was happening for me too, on my dell 2-in-1 laptop. For 6 months! I remember it stopped after Dell update services installed a **bios update**. This is still nothing, I have much worse artifact screenshots, but can't post them here.

Comment: @kitet very interestimg. Did you have the issue with the incorrect clock too?

Comment: No, I didn't have problems with the clock.